# Python: Changing filenames and folder names in all folders and subfolders

Tags: python

I want to change the file names and folder names in a given directory and all subfolders. My folder structure is as follows:

- top directory

  - file1
  - file2
  - folder1

    - file1
    - file2
    - file3
    - file4
  - folder2

    - file1
    - file2
    - file3
    - file4

I get the following error when executing the code below. I already checked the forums, but couldn't find a solution. Could someone please help me solve this issue and let me know what I need to do to get the program working? 
Or is there a better solution for renaming files and folders in a tree?

**Error message**

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'Filename 1' -> 'filename_1'

**Code**

```
#Change file names and folder names in a given directory and all its 
subfolders

import os

os.chdir("path\\to\\folder")
print(os.getcwd())

#Walk the directory and change the file names and folder names in all folders and subfolders.

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("path\\to\\folder"):
    for dir_name in dirs:
        os.rename(dir_name, dir_name.replace(" ", "_").lower())


    for file_name in files:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.replace(" ", "_").lower())



#Print done once all files have been renamed.      
print("done")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257878/python-os-rename-and-os-walk-together

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python os.rename and os.walk together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257878/python-os-rename-and-os-walk-together)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `root` otherwise the rename can't find the path:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("path/to/folder"):
    for name in dirs + files:
        os.rename(os.path.join(root, name), os.path.join(root, name.replace(" ", "_").lower()))
```

Answer (score 0):

could it be that you're walking on a folder while renaming it so that it can't be found?

looks like you first need to rename the files and only then the dirs (and even then - make sure it's bottom up)

Comment: I think you're right. But that's not formulated as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the filename first, otherwise you'll change the dir_name and lose reference.

Comment: first part isn't the issue since OP cd's to the proper dir (ok it's ugly)

Comment: and use `os.path.join` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution works most of the time, still issues like same name files may exist after normalizing the name.

```
import os

os.chdir("path/to/dir")
print(os.getcwd())

#Walk the directory and change the file names and folder names in all folders and subfolders.

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("path/to/dir", topdown=False):
   for file_name in files:
      new_name = file_name.replace(" ", "_").lower()
      if (new_name != file_name):
         os.rename(os.path.join(root, file_name), os.path.join(root, new_name))

   for dir_name in dirs:
      new_name = dir_name.replace(" ", "_").lower()
      if (new_name != dir_name):
         os.rename(os.path.join(root, dir_name), os.path.join(root, new_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I copied all files inside of each subfolder to another path.
First use `os.listdir()` to move through each folder, then use it to move through files which are inside of the folder path. Finally use `os.rename()` to rename file name. Here, I changed file name to folder name_file name which is "folder_file":

```
path = 'E:/Data1'
path1 = 'E:/Data2'
for folder in os.listdir(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path + '/'+ folder):
        src = path + '/' + folder + '/' + file
        des = path1 + '/' +  folder + '_' +file
        os.rename(src, des)
```